# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on AppDelegate when reloading data on tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm populating a tableView with custom cells. I get the cell label text and the imageView image from an array of tuples `(String:String)`where first value is a Shop Name and the second a Url for an image stored in firebase storage.
At the end of my query to firebase, I get the `availableShopsArray` populated, and reload data for the tableView. In the `cellForRowAt`function I assign the two parameters of the tuple to cell label and image. but on reloading data I get the error in AppDelegate.

here's how I declare the function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shopCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
   cell.shopNameLabel.text = self.availableShopsArray[indexPath.row].0
   let url = URL(string: self.availableShopsArray[indexPath.row].1)
   let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
   cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data:data!)
   return cell         
}
```

and this is my cell class:

```
import UIKit

class ShopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var makerImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopRatingLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Any idea of

Comment: show how you do reload in AppDelegate , Also is this the rootVC ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't do reload in `AppDelegate`, I simply call `self.availableShopsTableview.reloadData()` inside the function that gets the data from Firebase, in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is create an exception to try to find where the error is here's a helpful tutorial on how to do that: https://mukeshthawani.com/debug-the-sigabrt-error-exception

Comment: Great, I was able to point to the error. Basically leftover outlet references.
But now I'm having the found nil error in `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)`

It shouldn't be nil because the array is populated from the Firebase query and I get positive print of the array.
I know that the url is correct as I copied from Firebase Storage file, but I'm not sure if I do need to reference Firebase Storage or not sun the image Url.

Should I post a new question for this?